# How to update the source Option in bootstrap-typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using bootstrap-typeahead in order to allow multiple selection.
Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/BwDmM/3/).

The original code has been update by @Sherbrow [Twitter bootstrap typeahead multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662824/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-multiple-values)

My question is related to the following use case:
after inserting `Alaska` value, I would like to update the source not showing again `Alaska` value.
Any hints?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem and this one will save you a lot of time. I've updated your old [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BwDmM/62/) with my code example. The basic thing is that you need to do

```
var autocomplete = $('input').typeahead();
autocomplete.data('typeahead').source = newSource;
```

Where `newSource` is the new array. Now you just need a function that adds or removes an element, or whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: note!! You can also do this for updater. `
var newUpdater = function(item) {}
autocomplete.data('typeahead').updater = newUpdater; `
You rock man, i've been working on this for days!!

Answer (score 6):

None of the given answers worked for me, I had to destroy the original typeahead instance and re initialize it.

`$('input').typeahead('destroy').typeahead(options);`

Comment: Yup, the only one working for me as well. Using typeahead.js 0.10.5.

Comment: I'm using typeahead.js 0.11.1 (bundle) and it's not working for me :-(

Answer (score 2):

Based on the default `updater` method of typeahead :

```js
updater: function (item) {
  var pos = this.source.indexOf(item);
  if(pos != -1) {
    var newSource =
      this.source.slice(0,pos)
      .concat(this.source.slice(pos+1));
    this.source = newSource;
  }
  return item
}
```

[Demo with multiple values (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/BwDmM/67/)

Keep in mind that you can access this source from *anywhere* with `$('sel').data('typeahead').source` considering that the typeahead is initialized