# bootstrap typeahead - changing source

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I looking for a way to change `source` for typeahed.

For instance, assume I have the following 2 lists, and depend on the case, I'd like to have the typeahead workingin with a different source.

```
var list1 = ["this", "is", "first", "list"],
    list2 = ["second", "list", "comes", "here"];

$("selector").typeahead({source: list1})
```

Then, when I do

```
$("selector").typeahead({source: list2})
```

and start typing into the input box, the first list appears underneath the new one.

I tried doing

```
$("selector")
    .removeData()
    .typeahead({source: list2})
```

Yet, it has no effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update the source Option in bootstrap-typeahead.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516396/how-to-update-the-source-option-in-bootstrap-typeahead-js)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to update the data field associated as indicated [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1997#issuecomment-4011687) :

```
$("selector").data('typeahead').source = list2;
```

Comment: that's correct, just came across this at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1997#issuecomment-4011687

Comment: Yes, that is the same link that I have found :)

Comment: I'm getting Cannot set property 'source' of undefined

Answer (score 4):

None of these answers worked for me when using the [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) library.  I was able to update the source by destroy the initialized typeahead and re initializing it with a new source:

```
    $(".typeahead").typeahead("destroy");
    $(".typeahead").typeahead({ source: result });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also has the effect of destroying the events on that element...

Comment: Right, you'd need to apply them along with the source

Comment: Make sure to manually unbind any event handlers that you are using (e.g. 'typeahead:close') when you call the 'destroy' method. This method doesn't unbind these handlers, so they will keep appending and degrading performance each time you destroy and rebuild.

Comment: The answer of Samuel Caillerie does work for me on Bootstrap-3-Typeahead.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer didn't work for me. It could be an issue with newer versions of the library. For me, data('typeahead') isn't defined - instead there is data('ttTypeahead') and data('ttAttrs'). Neither of those has a source attribute.

After some code reading I came up with this:

`$('selector').data('ttTypeahead').dropdown.datasets[0].source = mySourceFunction`

And it seems to work. There might be instances where more than one dataset is defined, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your situation right, but as you said "*and depend on the case, I'd like to have the typeahead workingin with a different source*.", I think you can use a function as a source to `typeahead` instead of an array. Like so:

```js
function typeAheadSourceFunc(inputText) {
  if(inputText.length === 1) {
    return ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo'];
  } else {
    return ['OtherAmsterdam', 'OtherWashington', 'OtherSydney'];                  
  }
}
$("SOMESELECTORHERE").typeahead({ source: typeAheadSourceFunc });
```

`typeAheadSourceFunc` in this example will fire every time a `keypressed` fires on input and returns a different source. You probably can handle your situation there.

p.s: I am using `bootstrap3-typeahead.js v4.0.2`