# Update Twitter Typeahead.js (0.10.x) with local data

Tags: typeahead.js

Please note I don't mean the Bootstrap Typeahead solution [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562932/bootstrap-typeahead-changing-source) where updating the source with local data is very easy:

```
$("selector").data('typeahead').source = list2;
```

Unfortunately this now returns

> Cannot set property 'source' of undefined

and there is absolutely nothing in the current documentation on how to update the data.

Please note I would like to avoid using bloodhound.js or similar, all my data are local in JS my JS script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I am destroying and reinstantiating the whole Typeahead object with different local data.