# Autocomplete with restriction

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I am trying to do, using bootstrap, an autocomplete function which works over an inputText having to show the options list only when the related inputText contains more than 4 characters.
This is my xhtml:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      jQuery.noConflict();

      var autocompPerson = $('.autocomp'); 

      autocompPerson.typeahead({

      source: [#{operationsFormBean.allPersonFilteredList}],

      });
    });
</script>

<div class="col-md-8 pb0 pl0">
        <h:inputText id="auPerson"
            value="#{backingBeanRef['selectedPersonName']}"
            styleClass="form-control autocomp wo-borders bg-transparent">
         <a4j:ajax 
          event="keyup" listener="#{backingBeanRef['personFilteredList']}"
          render="operations_form_panel"/>
       </h:inputText>

</div>
```

The method personFilteredList() is in my java Bean and it is the one who controls if the input has or not more than 4 characters.

If I use the event "keyup", whenever I write a character in my inputText, I lose the focus over it and the list disappears immediatly. I know it is working since it shows the list only when I write more than 4 characters. The problem is : when the method is called I have to render the inputText in order to show the list and it makes me lose the focus over which makes the list disappears.

Do you know if I can use a js function like "updater" which updates my selectedPersonName every single time I write something without using the event keyup?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PrimeFaces contains builtin autocomplete functionality by `<p:autoComplete>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AJAX `oncomplete` JS callback hook to update your source for `typeahead` and re-render just the inputText. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516396/how-to-update-the-source-option-in-bootstrap-typeahead-js) for resetting the source in bootstrap typeahead.

Comment: That works almost properly. The problem is that using the event "keyup", and re-rendering the inputText, when I write a character, it shows the list and dissapear immediatly. I am trying to use something like: $('.typeahead').show(); but it isnt working.

Comment: Try nesting the `<script>` element inside of a `<h:panelGroup/>` and re-render that instead of the `<h:inputText/>`. It should cause your script to execute without messing with the inputText. If that works let me know and I'll update my answer

Comment: I have already tried it but the list doesn't appears, probably because of not rendering de input text.