# Autocomplete inputText event

Tags: javascript, jsf, events, input

I am trying to do an autocomplete with bootstrap styles and using jsf. Every time I write something on the input text field, I have to catch the event and do some stuff in my backing bean. I am trying something like this

```
<f:ajax event="keyup" render="myForm" listener="backingBeanMethod"/>
```

The problem is that each time I write something, I lose the focus on the field. The "change" event only works when I lose the focus of the field. Can I solve this problem using some js function or..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete with restriction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328720/autocomplete-with-restriction)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` event, something like that:

```
<f:ajax event="change" render="myForm" listener="backingBeanMethod"/>
```