# Hiding Option List in Bootstrap's Select2/ Chosen Upon Onclick?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-select2, jquery-chosen

I understand that for both select2/ chosen plugins, the whole list of options will be displayed once you click on the textbox. However, is it possible to hide the options and only show available list upon typing, just like the autocomplete? I was wondering as I want to use this API, but not sure if they can function like the autocomplete plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking is a bootstrap typeahead. Go through the following link: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: Hi @Prabhat, just wondering if typeahead also has this remove element that select2/ chosen has?

Comment: Yes for multiple select, typeahead does not have that functionality. So you will need to write javascript to achieve that functionality, for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662824/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-multiple-values . Also on looking at select2 api and examples, I think the features that you require should be possible.