# typeahead.js to select multiple values in same text element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js

Is there a way to get the solution referenced here:
[Twitter bootstrap typeahead multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662824/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-multiple-values)

To work with typeahead.js where updater, matcher etc functions are not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events you can read:

> typeahead:selected – Triggered when a suggestion from the dropdown
>   menu is selected. The event handler will be invoked with 3 arguments:
>   the jQuery event object, the suggestion object, and the name of the
>   dataset the suggestion belongs to.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3hL70h1L/

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
})
.on('typeahead:selected',
    function(event,suggestions) {
        $myTextarea.append(suggestions.value, ' '); 
        $('.typeahead').val('');
    }
);
```

Notice that you also can use [The Typeahead plugin from Twitter's Bootstrap 2 ready to use with Bootstrap 3](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) (can also be integrated with [Bloodhound](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead#bloodhound))

Both typeahead plugins also work together with [Bootstrap tags support](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), see https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead#bootstrap-tags-input which seems to offer a similar functionality.