# Highlight multiple words using Typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, search, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I'm using [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) for autocompletion, just like in [this official example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#bloodhound).

When I search for "rh" this results in "**Rh**ode Island" (the matching characters are highligted).

When I search for "rh is" this results in "Rhode Island" (without any highlighting). How can I get this to work? Expected result: "**Rh**ode **Is**land".

P.S. If this requires modifications to the [source code](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/src/typeahead/highlight.js) then this is OK for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662824/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-multiple-value

Comment: Thank you. But the link is for the typeahead component before bootstrap v2.3, and there's possibly no corresponding functions to override in Typeahead.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default integrated highlighting component of typeahead isn't smarth enough to fit your requirement.

I'm giving you an example with [mark.js](https://markjs.io), a text highlighter for search terms/keywords or custom regular expressions. Please have a look at the website to learn more about the API.

**DEMO [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/56enz0xg/2/)**

```js
$(function() {
  // constructs the suggestion engine
  var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
    'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
    'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
    'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
    'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
    'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
    'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
    'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
    'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming', 'take bag'
  ];
  var states = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
    local: states
  });

  // Initialize typeahead with mark.js
  var $context = $("#bloodhound");
  $context.find(".typeahead").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    // disable integrated typeahead component
    highlight: false,
    minLength: 1
  }, {
    name: 'states',
    source: states
  }).on("typeahead:render", function() {
    // highlight matches with mark.js
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    $context.find(".tt-menu").mark(searchTerm);
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px;
}

mark {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/julmot/mark.js/6.1.0/dist/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twitter/typeahead.js/v0.11.1/dist/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- Demo taken from http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ -->
<div id="bloodhound">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA. Type in 'rh is' or 'bag take'">
</div>
```

First, you will have to disable the default integrated highlighting component (disabled by default). Then, you'll have to listen for the renderer event and initialize [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) on the suggestions of typeahead.

Comment: Great answer! This is exactly what I was looking for. One extra question though: When I type 'a' it highlights all the a's in Alabama. Is it possible to only highlight the first a?

Comment: Thank you! Currently, it's not possible to limit the highlights to a specific amount of matches. But luckily another user (or are you?) requested the same feature a few hours ago, see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/issues/35). So if you'd like that this option will be implemented, please participate yourself.

Comment: However, you could always check the `searchTerm` against "a" for example and don't initialize mark.js in that case.

Comment: I didn't submit the feature request, so someone else did. Can't the behavior be achieved via a regular expression (markRegExp)?

Comment: @compie Please participate yourself in the [issue](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/issues/35) on GitHub to find a solution for your use case.

Comment: Use a newer version of mark.js which adds plenty more features: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/jquery.mark.min.js

Answer (score -1):

I think if you add `\s` pattern to the regex used in `_.escapeRegExChars()` helper (see [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/src/common/utils.js#L21)), it will solve your problem.

I am not certainly sure, because I'm not answering from my laptop, and I can't do tests, but you can try and let me now.