# Select multiple options with shift or ctrl key from dropdown list using ajax typeahead bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

**Note:-** I am using **bootstrap AJAX typeahead** https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead If possible please provide answer according to this plug-in.

I have seen this link [Twitter bootstrap typeahead multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662824/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-multiple-values) In which user can select only single option and then dropdown list disappeared.But I want Dropdowon list should remain active and then user select as many as option he wants with **shift or ctrl key** and selected options should be entered in input field with comma separated.

**How can I add above functionality in my code?**

```
Full: <input id="full"></input><br/><br/>

var fullSource = [{ id: 1, name: 'John'}, { id: 2, name: 'Alex'}, { id: 3, name: 'Terry'},{ id: 1, name: 'Tonny'},{ id: 1, name: 'Ravi'},{ id: 1, name: 'XYZ'},{ id: 1, name: 'Tom'},{ id: 1, name: 'Rajesh'},{ id: 1, name: 'James'}];

$('#full').typeahead({
source: fullSource,
 valueField: 'name',
displayField: 'id'
});
```

Here is sample code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mukesh_tejra/V6U2r/5/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap typeahead multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662824/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-multiple-values)

Comment: Not exactly. I want dorpdown list active until user select as many as options and selected text added in input field. The link you mentioned above in which user can select only one option at a time then dropdown list disappear. I do not want dropdown disappear after selecting single option..

Comment: I guess typeahead alone is not the right tool for the job. Have you considered something like a tag editor (including typeahead for completion), f.i.: http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: I want to use typeahead instead bootstrap-tagsinput because I have made so much changes already in my project using typeahead.   Can you tell me how to keep active dropdown list after selecting options and also able to select multiple options with shift or ctlr key without disappearing dropdown list.