# Angular Bootstrap Typeahead - check multiple words in one input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

**Short Overview about the environment**

I am writing an app on the CEAN Stack which should does the following:

- The couchbase contains a big amount of large JSON documents
- I fetch a bunch of JSON Keys from documents in the Couchbase
- The user has a input field where he can enter filter criteria to find specific documents (e.g. "key1 = 10 & key2 > 20")

**Current Approach**

Currently I use the Angular Bootstrap Typeahead Plugin.
So when the user enters a letter the app should search in the fetched JSON keys to find keys which start with the entered search string. (e.g. user types "ke" and the app serves a list with ("key1", "key2", ...).

This is the common use-case for this plugin.

**My Problem**

I want the input box to behave like a text autocompletion. So when the user starts typing, the app guesses the key. (Let's say he types "ke" and selects key1). Now the user keeps on writing and the app should check for new words. (e.g. the content of the input is now "key1 = 10 & ke" and the app should now suggest the matching keys again( e.g. "key2"). Is this possible with this plugin or do you suggest an other solution for this problem?

Thanks in Advance!

```
example:
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lgFpCmciLlDfsj7OXPts?p=preview)

Plunker with current approach (I took the states because I can not provide the real keys but for the sake of clearifing the problem it should be enough)
So when I write "Alabama Te" it should suggest["Texas", Tennesse"] again.

Comment: Please provide working code that shows your issue.

Comment: you can use ng-autocomplete which is more easy and clear!

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4REC7U1xUxiFb7Qa4Xd?p=preview

Comment: @BhaumikThakkar this plnkr is not working as intended. You just can select one country at one time

Comment: +1 for this question. Any suggestions? I found this answer, but there are hack with comma, but we can enter in RegExp own rules (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662824/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-multiple-values)