# Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead Multiple Values in Google Apps Script

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-apps-script, typeahead

I'm trying to implement a solution I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662824/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-multiple-values) in Google Apps Script (GAS).  It works great in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/BwDmM/300/), but there's something I'm missing on account of which it's not working [in GAS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FCtN7GANjlndw6Ii7txLgvxASbHhHAgKWUFs0TyaBSg/edit?usp=sharing).  Here are my two files that comprise the Google Apps Script implementation of the solution.  Can you help me please?

**Code.gs**

```
function setUpNewSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('typeahead')
           .evaluate()
           .setTitle('Title')
           .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
         SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

**typeahead.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<input type="text" class="typeahead" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

!function(source) {
    function extractor(query) {
        var result = /([^,]+)$/.exec(query);
        if(result && result[1])
            return result[1].trim();
        return '';
    }

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: source,
        updater: function(item) {
            return this.$element.val().replace(/[^,]*$/,'')+item+',';
        },
        matcher: function (item) {
          var tquery = extractor(this.query);
          if(!tquery) return false;
          return ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(tquery.toLowerCase())
        },
        highlighter: function (item) {

          var query = extractor(this.query).replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
          return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
            return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
          })
        }
    });

}(["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Dakota","North Carolina","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]);

});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: A few issues. 1) All content must be linked over tls. 2) css isn't linked the same as javascript 3) you never included jquery 4) you never included the jquery typeahead plugin. Your best bet is to look at the typeahead github page and go off their docs.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been stuck on this for weeks.  Many, many thanks to you Spencer!

For anyone wishing to benefit from Spencer's fix, it's located in the html file at this link:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FCtN7GANjlndw6Ii7txLgvxASbHhHAgKWUFs0TyaBSg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: No prob. You should post your fix as an answer then select it. This helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to Spencer for this working solution!  To get this to work in GAS, the typeahead.html file should be updated to the following (big changes are in the head tag, and the Code.gs file remains unchanged):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
</head>

<input type="text" class="typeahead" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

!function(source) {
    function extractor(query) {
        var result = /([^,]+)$/.exec(query);
        if(result && result[1])
            return result[1].trim();
        return '';
    }

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: source,
        updater: function(item) {
            return this.$element.val().replace(/[^,]*$/,'')+item+',';
        },
        matcher: function (item) {
          var tquery = extractor(this.query);
          if(!tquery) return false;
          return ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(tquery.toLowerCase())
        },
        highlighter: function (item) {

          var query = extractor(this.query).replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
          return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
            return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
          })
        }
    });

}(["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Dakota","North Carolina","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]);

});
</script>
</html>
```